# how to configure gulp-mocha with the following mocha.opts configuration?

Tags: mocha.js, e2e-testing, gulp-mocha

I am trying to run mocha with gulp with the configuration existed before.
    moch.opts has the following line.

```
--timeout 999999
--ui tdd
--full-trace
--recursive
--compilers js:babel-register
```

how to add them here :

```
    gulp.task('test', function() {
        return gulp.src('sampleTest/*.js', { read: false })
            .pipe(mocha());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can either create properties on the options object passed to `gulp-mocha` or you can just have it read the options file. In my case, I didn't want to duplicate things like `--recursive` or `--require test/_init.js`, but I did want to override the reporter, so I use the code shown below:

```js
gulp.task('test', ['compile'], function() {
    return gulp.src([], { read: false })
        .pipe(mocha({
            opts: 'test/mocha.opts',
            reporter: 'min'
        }))
        .on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

You may want to modify this so that it doesn't assume the default path to test files (e.g. `test/*.js`), but in my simple case I didn't even need to pass a path to mocha. I'm just using gulp to trigger it (as if I had run on the command line something like `mocha --opts test/mocha.opts --reporter min`)

Answer (score 0):

Options are passed **directly** to the **mocha** binary, so you can use any its command-line options in a **camelCased** form. [this is the document link](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-mocha#options)

```
gulp.task('test', ['compile'], function() {
return gulp.src([], { read: false })
    .pipe(mocha({
        timeout: 999999,
        fullTrace: true,
        reporter: 'min'
    }))
    .on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

add the setTimeout call after the mocha call

```
.pipe(mocha(),setTimeout(function() {

}, 999999))
```

Comment: How does one get to make these down voters leave a comment as to why they downvote?